# C Programming while loops

Tags: c, do-while

```
void main()
{
    int a;
    a=10;
    do
    while(a++<10);
    while(a++<=11);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

The above program gives an output of `14`.
Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly braces would make it more readable, but as you have it, the execution flow and values of ***a*** are explained in line:

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation. But why does the it leave when a is 14 instead of 13?

Comment: @Deant -   Look at the 4th step.  It enters the loop at 13, fails the evaluation because 13 is not <= 11, but is post-incremented to 14 _before_ it leaves the outer loop.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This code will make you understand why , Whenever you type a++ its always incremented

```
void main()
{
    int a;
    a=10;
    do{
    while(a++<10);
    printf("%d",a);
}
    while(a++<=11);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: More Confusion. The output is 11 13 and 14. i understand that the first value of a is post incremented to get 11. but how do you explain the 13 and the 14.

Answer (score 2):

Here your code evaluate as

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a=10;
    do{
           //---> second iteration a= 12, for post iteration in while

        while(a++<10);  // First iteration: a=10 ,so false| second Iteration: a=12, so false

        //First iteration: Here a=11, as previous line's post increment| Second iteration: here a=13, as previous post increment

    } while(a++<=11);  //First iteration: a==11, that evaluete true, go to --->, line after do | Second iteration: a=13, false, loop end goto next line

    //Here a=14 for post increment in previous line's while loop

    printf("%d",a);   // a=14
}
```

In post increment first evaluate the expression with current value then increment the value of the variable.

For example in second iteration when program start execution on outer while `while(a++<=11)`, this time `a=13` as previous value of `a`. This `a++<=11` execute and return `0` which makes `while(0)` (Because a=13, which is greater than 11). Then increment occur and a becomes 14. As `while(0)` it break the do-while loop and  goes to next instruction and print the value 14.

Comment: Pretty clear explanation.but if the conditions are false why does 14 get printed

Comment: @Deant, answer edited, may be you can understand this time.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, this is evil.  Reformatting the code a bit should show what's happening:

```
a=10;
do
{
  while(a++<10);
}
while(a++<=11);
```

So.  `a` is initially set to `10`.  We enter the `do while` loop.  The only statement in the `do while` loop is `while( a++ < 10 );`.  Remember that the expression `a++` *evaluates* to the current value of `a`, and as a *side effect* increments `a`.

So, `a++ < 10` is evaluated.  The result is `false` (`10` is not less than `10`), but as a result of evaluating the expression, `a` is incremented and now has value `11`.  At the end of the `do while` loop, we evaluate `a++<=11`.  This evaluates to `true` since `a` currently has the value of `11`.  As a result of evaluating the expression, `a` is incremented to `12`.

We execute the body of the `do while` loop again.  The expression `a++ < 10` is evaluated again.  Like before, the result is `false`, but as a result of evaluating the expression `a` is incremented to `13`.

We then evaluate `a++ <= 11` again.  The result is `false`, since `13` is not less than or equal to `11`, and `a` is incremented *one more time*.

Thus, by the time this whole mess is finished, `a` is `14`.

Summarizing:

1. `a` is initially `10`;
2. `do while` loop is entered
3. `a++ < 10` is evaluated, `a` is now `11`
4. `a++ <= 11` is evaluated, `a` is now `12`, `do while` loop repeats
5. `a++ < 10` is evaluated, `a` is now `13`
6. `a++ <= 11` is evaluated, `a` is now `14`, `do while` loop exits.

Comment: Pretty detailed explanation. Thanks a lot. But why does it stop at 14?

Comment: @Deant: I thought the explanation above made that pretty clear - we evaluate `a++ < 10` twice and `a++ <= 11` twice, meaning we evaluate `a++` four times total; this effectively adds `4` to the initial value of `a`.  `14` is not less than or equal to `11`, which is why the `do while` loop exits after the second iteration.

Comment: Just got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well the post increment will only happen after the condition is evaluated so `a` will get incremented even if the condition is false and may add more runs of the loop then you are expecting.

Comment: I know post increments are applied here, but how are they applied?

Comment: *"how are they applied?"* As the answer says: after the condition has been evaluated. `a` is incremented four times, because the outer `while` loop is executed twice and each of its two statements increments `a`. Indent the code properly and it will be easier to see.

Comment: Pretty much you need to understand that the last print only happens once as it is outside the second while "block"(this is why 12 is not printed). So while it still will count to 14 as a is incremented 4 times, only three prints will ever happen (namely 11, 13, 14).